# Excel: Search with multiple criteria with multiple results

Tags: excel

I think the header says the most. But I'm kind of new in excel and need a bit of help.
I'm trying to make a search-function for my projectlibary.
I have a multiple `cells(A10:H10)` that will be the criterias: Projectnumber, Engineer... Material, House type, building part.. and so on. See picture 1.

[image: Picture 1]

And i have a `sheet(Sheet1)` where my projectlibary is (`A22:H8000`). And you add projects to the libary with the same criteria.
What i want is that, if i search for a Material: Steel, i will get all the projects that contain steel.
And if i search for both Material: Steel and Buildingpart: Roof, i will get projects that contain both of them... and so on.

Maybe a bad explanation, and i will answer questions quickly as i can.

Comment: FILTER() function will help you. Read this article from [exceljet](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function).

Comment: If VBA is an option, try these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7ScsebMq5uV493VqnVEIY35SKxUKwWHM).

Comment: Good question! How do you mean "I will get all the projects that [match the criteria]" - do you mean you'll be given the number of how many there are, or they'll be somehow highlighted for you, or something else?

Comment: @SpencerBarnes Well i would say it should be like a search-engine. If i search for "Steel" it will search-up and get all the projects with the "Steel" criteria. Like the FILTER-function.

Comment: @VBasic2008 That looks like the filter i'm looking for. I'll give it a try.